# How to remove blank and null values from a list that passed into dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe column like below.

```
df['lane']
AZ
NL

NaN
BL
AZ
```

**My code**

```
unique_lane = df['lane'].unique()
unique_lane = pd.DataFrame( list(zip(unique_lane)), columns =['unique_lane'])
t = ', '.join(unique_lane['unique_lane'].astype(str))
```

While I am passing unique list values blank('') or Null values should be removed from the list.
The list t created should contain not blank or  not Null values.

```
bigdata_null_zones = bigdata_null_zones[~bigdata_null_zones["lane"].isin([t])]
```

How can this be done in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data for test DataFrame from question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lane':['AZ','NL','', np.nan, 'BL','AZ']})
```

Test for pass only misisng values or empty strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lane':['', np.nan]})
print (df)
  lane
0     
1  NaN

bigdata_null_zones = pd.DataFrame({'lane':['AZ','NL','AB', 'BL','AZ']})
print (bigdata_null_zones)
  lane
0   AZ
1   NL
2   AB
3   BL
4   AZ
```

After remove it get empty `Series`:

```
t = df['lane'].replace('',np.nan).dropna()
print (t)
Series([], Name: lane, dtype: float64)
```

So if pass get same values, because nothing filtered:

```
bigdata_null_zones[bigdata_null_zones["lane"].isin(t)]
print (bigdata_null_zones)
  lane
0   AZ
1   NL
2   AB
3   BL
4   AZ
```

If same DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lane':['AZ','NL','', np.nan, 'BL','AZ'],
                   'col':range(6)})

print (df)
  lane  col
0   AZ    0
1   NL    1
2         2
3  NaN    3
4   BL    4
5   AZ    5

df1 = df.assign(lane= df['lane'].replace('',np.nan)).dropna(subset=['lane'])
print (df1)
  lane  col
0   AZ    0
1   NL    1
4   BL    4
5   AZ    5
```

Comment: `bigdata_null_zones =bigdata_null_zones[~bigdata_null_zones["lane"].isin([t])]`. Will this line  of code break if I have no values inside t beacuse `df[lane]` had only blank or null values

Comment: @s - Unfortunately not understand.

Comment: My orginal daframe `df['lane']` has only null and blank values  only. then I apply your code remove those using code `t = df['lane'].replace('',np.nan).dropna()`. After this I pass this inside the second dataframe. I am asking in such a case will the code break

Comment: @snehanair - I can test, but I think not.

Comment: @jazrael, In that case `t` doesnt have any value so will the `isin` condition work Thats my question

Comment: @snehanair - Understand, added to answer to see working correctly.

Comment: @jazreal,`bigdata_null_zones.lane.unique()` is `array([''], dtype=object)`. If my  secondary daframe contains blank values  that is getting filtered. I am missing something

Comment: @snehanair - reason should be no empty values in orignal `df['lane']`, so not filtered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215017/discussion-between-sneha-nair-and-jezrael).